# Problem with wordpress links on a live site

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to create a website at the following link: http://www.knowthelaw.in/

The website was created with wordpress using the twentyeleven theme. The problem I am facing is as follows:

As soon as you agree to the disclaimer and hit the "Proceed to .. " button, you are served with a 404 error. The page it redirects to is the "Welcome!" page which can also be accessed from the "About" section. Apart from this one page, all other pages work OK. This problem is not seen in the wordpress website on localhost.

What I have done so far:
 1. Checked all permalinks.
 2. Changed the link for the "Proceed .. " button to a `?page_id` link. This does not work.
3. Kept the permalink in the drop-down menu. This too does not work.

I am at my wits end to figure out what the problem is. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: @stealthyninja: you were spot on! I changed the slug for the page to `welcome2` and it worked. When I look at the FTP file manager on goDaddy, I see that there is a `welcome.html` file present there which is a filler if your site is not yet up. Should I delete that file? Also, why don't you make your comment an answer? I could accept that.

Comment: Ok, I've added it as an answer now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The welcome page "exists" since I can access it when I [search for it](http://www.knowthelaw.in/?s=welcome&submit=Search), though trying to go to its link directly give me a 404 as well. As an experiment, try changing that page's slug to `welcome2`; if it works now, check if you have any custom rewrite rules set up that are overriding the welcome page.

> I see that there is a `welcome.html` file present there which is a filler if your site is not yet up.

Rename it to `_welcome.html`, set your page's slug back to `welcome` and try accessing [your welcome page](http://www.knowthelaw.in/welcome/) directly again afterwards (force re-load the page since you might still see the 404 come up at least once).